# Get current terminal color pair in Perl

Tags: perl, termcap

I'm trying to learn about color text in a terminal window. (In case it matters I'm using Terminal.app on OS X.) I'd like to get the terminal's current foreground and background color pair. It looks like I should be able to get this info in a perl script using the Term::Cap library, but the solution eludes me.

In a perl script how would I query the terminal's current foreground and background color pair value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is outside the scope of terminfo and termcap, because it deals with *terminal responses*, while terminfo/termcap describe these capabilities:

- how to tell the terminal to do some commonly-implemented *feature* (such as clearing the screen), or
- what sequence of characters might some *special key* (such as <kbd>*Home*</kbd>) send from the keyboard.

While in principle, there is no limitation on what *could* be part of a terminal description, there was little commonality across terminals back in the 1980s for *responses*.  A few terminals could report specific features, most of those were constant (e.g., version information).  Most of the variable responses came after terminfo/termcap had more or less solidified in X/Open Curses.  [ncurses extends that](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_N_C_U_R_S_E_S__U_S_E_R-_D_E_F_I_N_A_B_L_E__C_A_P_A_B_I_L_I_T_I_E_S), but again, most of the extensions are either *features* or *special keys*.

Terminal.app implements the most commonly-used features of **`xterm`**, but (like other imitators) omits most of the terminal responses.  Among other things, **`xterm`** provides terminal responses which can tell an application what the window's colors are currently.  There are a couple of command-line utilities ([**`xtermset`**](https://sourceforge.net/p/clts/wiki/Home/) and [**`xtermcontrol`**](https://thrysoee.dk/xtermcontrol/)) which have been written to use this information (and again, they cover only a part of the repertoire).  Using **`xtermcontrol`** demonstrates that Terminal.app is lacking in this area — see screenshot:

[image: screenshot showing Terminal.app vs xterm using xtermcontrol]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think most terminals support reporting this -- and it doesn't look like termcap or terminfo have any entries for it. You're just expected to *set* the color pair as necessary, not to ask the terminal what it's set to right now. In the ECMA-48 standard (better known as "ANSI" after ANSI X3.64, where it used to live), the only command that makes reference to color is SGR "Set Graphic Rendition", which is purely write-only.

Comment: I think you are correct. I did read through lots of man pages and was coming to the same conclusion that the current color pair is a write-only property, but since terminal programming is all new to me I wanted to ask in case there was something I missed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno about perl or Terminal.app, but xterm etc will write foreground/background color control sequences to stdin if you output `"\033]10;?\07"` or `"\033]11;?\07"` respectively. Check out http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html, http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Controls in particular.